# How can you reformat text in TextMate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, textmate

Is there a command in TextMate to re-indent or format text in a file?

I use this all the time in IDE's after pasting in a block of code, removing a block, etc for re-indenting a file.

Bonus points if there is a way to pretty indent, turning this:

```
has_many :users, :class_name => 'Users', :dependent => :destroy
has_many :comments, :class_name => 'Comments', :dependent => :destroy
```

into this:

```
has_many :users,    :class_name => 'Users',    :dependent => :destroy
has_many :comments, :class_name => 'Comments', :dependent => :destroy
```

But even just simple reformatting would be awesome.

Not sure if it matters but I'm mostly talking about Ruby-on-Rails apps here.

Comment: if there is a bundle out there that does this, please let us know. funny, i was just wondering this about 10 min ago.

Comment: Yeah, this is one of those features that long time TextMate users never miss because they've never had it.  But once tasting the forbidden IDE fruit it's hard to go without it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sweet!

This bundle adds it for Ruby code: http://github.com/mocoso/code-beautifier.tmbundle#readme

It only indents Ruby code (not HTML or anything else), and doesn't do the pretty indent (only regular indenting), but still - it re-indents the whole file with one command.

Edit: just realized another way to do it with a built in TextMate feature.
option-apple-[
This indents one line.  So if you do ctrl-a (to select all) and then option-apple-[ it has a similar effect (although it's two commands instead of one, and loses where you had the cursor)

Answer (score 1):

Pretty indent? No way. I had no idea there was something called that. I'll be watching this thread.

For now I use apple + '[' or ']'

And make sure I have my indentions set to soft spaces.

I can't say that's exactly what you're looking for..

Comment: Yep, not exactly but I figure I can't be the first one to want this.  I use the apple + '[' or ']' to indent individual lines or selections, but it's a poor substitute for re-indenting the whole file with one key combo.